# “display table-cell” with different heights when increase/decrease browser zoom

Tags: html, css

Hy all, 
I have a problem in displaying a table built with div + css when I increase or decrease the browser's zoom. The cell with the image (which from height to row) increases or decreases in size, and I don't understand why. The image is 35x35px and the cell has 10px padding top and bottom.
Here's a screenshot of the problem and some source code.
I really have no idea why this behavior

EDIT: Additional info, the table is inside an `<iframe>` element

[image]

```css
    .table-custom {
        font-size: 12px;
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .table-row {
        display: table-row;
        color: #333;
    }
    .col {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 10px 3px;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #666;
    }
    .col-1 {
        width: 25%;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .col-2 {
        width: 15%;
    }
    .col-2 img{

        width: 35px;
        height: 35px;
    }
    .col-3 {
        width: 60%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="table-custom">
     <div class="table-row clearfix">
      <div class="col col-1">
       <a href="...">sometxt</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-2">
       <a href="..."> <img class="sua" src="https://i.imgur.com/wxROuzQ.png"> </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-3">
       <a href="...">sometxt</a>
      </div>
     </div>
        <div class="table-row clearfix">
      <div class="col col-1">
       <a href="...">sometxt</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-2">
       <a href="..."> <img class="sua" src="https://i.imgur.com/wxROuzQ.png"> </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-3">
       <a href="...">sometxt</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve], where the image is properly linked, so we can see what goes on, preferably using a [Stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/2827823)

Comment: This is probably because the content. What you can do is add the border in the row not in the cell. This way it doesnt matter which size the column has.

Comment: i added the image. The problem occur when you zoom out to 67%. Or if you increase zoom in to 110%

Comment: @RicardoFerreira probably because the content what? I had tried your solution and it works obviously.  But what i wanna to know there is why this behavior occurs. I can also tell you that the problem is solved by decreasing image size to 30px or less.

Comment: When you use the zoom everything is increased proportionally. So, as you have different types of content inside of your column, hence you have different proportions. Try to put exactly the same content in both of them and you will understand what I mean.

Comment: OK, i know what you're telling, but why? displaying table row -> table cell should grant me the same height in all cell, independently of the content...or I am wrong?

Answer (score -1):

If you zoom in or out your browser it will increase or decrease all the elements. But when you resize your your browser window it will not do that. Everything remains same. If the unit of width and height is in percentage, it will be resized as screen's  width and height.